# Which one is the correct formula of confidence interval of variance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, confidence-interval, variance, references

I got the following formula of confidence interval of variance in [this site](http://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/06evar.html)

$$\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{1-(\alpha/2),n-1}}<\sigma^2<\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{(\alpha/2),n-1}}$$

And this following formula in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqB5a7_W44) and [here](http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/ci-variances.htm) :

$$\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{(\alpha/2),n-1}}<\sigma^2<\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{1-(\alpha/2),n-1}}$$

The denominator is confusing me .

Which one is correct ?

Comment: Both may be correct, if they define what they mean by those symbols differently

Comment: They seem to define the chi-squared quantiles differently, all leading to correct answers. The explanation in the video is neat!

Comment: @MichaelM from video it seems to me , in `R` code $\chi^2_{\alpha/2}=$`qchisq(alpha/2,df=n-1,lower.tail=FALSE)` , and $\chi^2_{1-(\alpha/2)}=$`qchisq(1-(alpha/2),df=n-1)` . And both produces the same result .

Comment: Right. In my script, I use the first version (which seems a bit more straightforward).

Answer (score 6):

That's because chi-square distribution notations differ in different books
your first formula is the one with the common notation which also used in R that is:

$$P(X\lt\chi^2)=p$$

[image: Chi-Square Distribution]

But in some books the notation is this:

$$P(X\lt\chi^2)=1-p$$

You can rewrite your formulas free of notation by the help of this image:

[image: Chi-Square Distribution]

$$\frac{(n-1)s^2}{b}\lt\sigma^2\lt\frac{(n-1)s^2}{a}$$

Comment: +1 An illustrated answer is usually worth reading.  Welcome to our site!